# How to add some new code to an existing EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Bear with me, what I am requesting may be impossible. I am a AWS noob.

So I am going to describe to you the situation I am in...

I am doing a freelance gig and was essentially handed the keys to AWS. That is, I was handed the root user login credentials for the AWS account that powers this website.

Now there are 3 EC2 instances. One of the instances is a linux box that, from what I am being told, is running a Django Python backend.

My new "service" if you will must exist within this instance.

How do I introduce new source code into this instance? Is there a way to pull down the existing source code that lives within it?

I am not be helped by any existing/previous developers so I am kind of just handed the AWS credentials and have no idea where to start.

Is this even possible. That is, is it possible to pull the source code from an EC2 instance and/or modify the code? How do I do this?

Comment: Can you login into the instance?

Comment: by logging in, do you mean ssh?

Comment: yes. all code should be there if its running the app?

Comment: so you're saying ssh into the ec2 instance and download it locally and analyze from there?

Comment: That would be good start.

Comment: If you can login (ssh) then you should be able to transfer files using WInSCP or a similar file transfer program. Then you have to hunt down where the code is (might be /var/django/something but could be inside other stuff). With Python/Django the good news is that there is no compile/link/build/make process - just find the code and make changes. But you will have to figure out how to activate the changes - that can vary a bit depending on the web server, wsgi, etc.

Comment: ok guys. I'll ssh tomorrow and dig around. Thanks. If I have any questions I'll leave a comment here also DM if you want to help ($$)

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instances are just virtual machines. So you can use SSH/SCP/SFTP files to and from.  You can use the AWS CLI tools to copy stuff from S3.  Dealers choice...

Now to get into this instance... If you look in the web console you can find its IP(s), what the security groups (firewall rules), and the [key pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-keypairs.html) name.  Hopefully they gave you the keys.  You need these [to SSH in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html).

You'll also want to check to make sure there's a security group applied that has SSH open. Hopefully only to your IP :)

If you don't have the keys you'll have to [create an AMI image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html) of the instance so you can create a new one with a [key pair](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-keypairs.html) you do have.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has a set of tools for you in Amazon CodeSuite.

The tool used for "deploying" the code is [Amazon CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/). By using this service you install an agent onto your host, then when triggered it will pull down an artifact of a code base and install it matching hosts. You can even specify additional commands through the [hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) system.

But you also want to trigger this to happen, maybe even automatically? CodeDeploy can be orchestrated using the [CodePipeline tool](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/).